# Latex Math Symbol: Vitanyi puts a tiny plus symbol over his equals. How do I do that?

Tags: math, latex, symbols

For example, in http://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/papers/algorithmicstatistics.pdf at the bottom of page 5 and top of page 6, he uses a plus/equal symbol and a similar plus/lessthan symbol.  I can't figure out how to make that symbol, and I'd like to quote him.

Any help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `$\stackrel{top}{bottom}$`

You'd want something like this:

```
$X \stackrel{+}{=} Y$
```

This positions the plus sign above the equals sign. For example, the following code:

```
$K(x,y|z) \stackrel{+}{=} K(x|z) \stackrel{+}{<} I(x:y|z)$
```

produces the following output:

[image: Equation including + sign over = sign]

Answer (score 4):

[The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/)) is a great resource, and start for questions like this.  You could also contact the author, it's possible he did some LaTex voodoo (math accents and such) to get it to work.

Best of luck.

PS: isn't \pm plus-minus, not plus-equals?

Comment: yeah, \pm is plus minus... he could have done \bar{\pm} or something crazy, like you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the list of [Latex Math Symbols](http://web.ift.uib.no/Fysisk/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html).  I don't see the two from the PDF you linked to.  Do you know what they mean?  You might be able to find an equivalent in the Latex list.